# Different behaviors when return place inside and after try

Tags: java, outputstream, try-catch-finally, finally, try-finally

I have following two code block, which I use to compress a String.

## code 1

```
public static String compressResponse(String response) throws IOException {

    Deflater deflater = new Deflater(Deflater.DEFLATED, true);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DeflaterOutputStream deflaterOutputStream = new DeflaterOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream, deflater);
    try {
        deflaterOutputStream.write(response.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        return Base64.encodeBytes(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DONT_BREAK_LINES);
    } finally {
        deflaterOutputStream.close();
    }
}
```

## code 2

```
 public static String compressResponse(String response) throws IOException {

    Deflater deflater = new Deflater(Deflater.DEFLATED, true);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DeflaterOutputStream deflaterOutputStream = new DeflaterOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream, deflater);
    try {
        deflaterOutputStream.write(response.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    } finally {
        deflaterOutputStream.close();
    }
    return Base64.encodeBytes(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DONT_BREAK_LINES);
}
```

Only the second method works fine where first method always return an empty String. I understand the this different behavior occurs due to different placement of return block with respect to finally block. What is the exact behavior for this?

Comment: The [`close` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.html#close--) says *writes remaining compressed data to the output stream and closes the underlying stream*. Presumably, if you don't `close` there is *remaining* data (i.e. all of it) that hasn't been written to the stream (see also [`flush`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.html#flush--)). Also, I would prefer a [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  " *there is remaining data (i.e. all of it)* " is it right? I knew if we dont call ``close()`` still there is a huge chance that some stream will be transmitted; close() ensure to get 100% data. Am I wrong?

Comment: @rev_dihazum It's buffered; there might be any (or no) content remaining in the buffer if you don't `flush` it. Which can lead to very difficult bugs.

Comment: yes.... but my question was: no stream will be transmitted before calling ``close()``? I knew stream will be transmitted ; close just flush the buffer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because in the first method the return statement is executed before you do the `deflaterOutputStream.close();` While the second do the close operation first

`deflaterOutputStream` writes the data to `byteArrayOutputStream` when it close the connection. Until `deflaterOutputStream` is closed, `byteArrayOutputStream` doesn't contain data.

Comment: How does closing deflaterOutputStream after returning affect the output of the method? If it hasn't closed, still Base64.encodeBytes(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DONT_BREAK_LINES) should return a correct value, isn't it?

Comment: No, it is supposed that if you don't close it, it won't release the memory and won't write, it means that it doesn't return the correct value...

Comment: So when we close deflatedOutputStream, it write/flush the values to byteArrayOutputStream?

Comment: Exactly, just as @dur said

Answer (score 2):

On the second example `byteArrayOutputStream` gets populated because `deflaterOutputStream` is closed and **flushed**.

Answer (score -1):

Even though you placed `return` statement in try block, your finally block will executes, functionality of `finally` block is,

> If exception raised or not raised, even though if exception raised and handled or not handled then `finally`  block will execute, finally block won't execute if you place `system.exit()` in `try` or `catch` block

In your code

```
try{
return------> this wont return instead finally block will execute
}
finally{
//
}
```

Your closing `DeflaterOutputStream` and it flushed so it is returning empty